# Modeling Client Context in WCF Web API with MEF

Tags: wcf-web-api

I need to extract several header values at the start of each request and place them into a ClientContext object that can be injected into my application code by MEF.  I am using Preview 5 of the WCF Web API and don't see a way to do this.

In 'standard' WCF, I would create a class that implements IExtension<OperationContext> and have the following property to wire it all together:

```
[Export(typeof(IClientContext)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public static ClientContextExtension Current
{
    get
    {
        var operationContext = OperationContext.Current;

        if (operationContext == null)
            return null;

        var extension = operationContext.Extensions.Find<ClientContextExtension>();

        if (extension == null)
        {
            extension = new ClientContextExtension();

            operationContext.Extensions.Add(extension);
        }

        return extension;
    }
}
```

A custom DelegatingHandler calls ClientContextExtension.Current and sets the properties from the header values. Unfortunately, with WCF Web API, OperationContext.Current is always null!

I cannot figure out a way to make this work with the Web API. Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a working solution but remain open to other options.  First, some rationale behind the original approach...

Because WCF uses thread pooling, anything based on a per-thread model may (and will) have a lifetime that extends beyond an individual request.  I needed a way to store client context information pulled from the HTTP headers for each request as the information will be different each time. This means I can't persist the context information per-thread because the thread will be re-used.

Or can I?

The flaw in my logic was that thread re-use was the problem. In reality, each thread is only every servicing a single request at one time thereby making any information in that thread isolated to that request.  Therefore, all I need to do is make sure that the information is relavent to that request and my problem is solved.

My solution was to refactor the Current property to reference a private static field marked with the [ThreadStatic()] attribute, ensuring that each instance was specific to the thread.  Then, in my DelegatingHandler, which executes for each request, I reset the properties of the object for that request.  Subsequent calls to Current during that request return the request-specific information and the next request handled by the thread gets updated in the DelegatingHandler so as far as my other code is concerned, the context is per-request.

Not perfect, but it at least gets me up and running for the moment.  As I said, I am open to other solutions.

**UPDATE**

Upon closer inspection, this solution is not working as there is no thread affinity between the DelegatingHandler and the service code that is making use of the context object. As a result, sometimes my call to retrieve the ThreadStatic object works as expected but on other occasions I get a new instance because the code is operating on a different thread than the handler.

So, disregard this solution. Back to the drawing board.

**UPDATE TO MY UPDATE**

After discussing my problem with Glenn Block, it turns out that it is just a matter of making sure the context is set on the same thread the request handler (the service) is executing.  The solution is to use an HttpOperationHandler instead of a MessageHandler.

According to Glenn, message handlers operate asynchronously which means they could execute on a different thread from the request handler (service) so we should never do anything in a message handler that requires thread affinity.  On the other hand, operation handlers run synchronously on the same thread as the request handler, therefore we can rely on thread affinity.

So, I simply moved my code from a MessageHandler to an HttpOperationHandler and have the desired results.

You can read a full explanation here: http://sonofpirate.blogspot.com/2011/11/modeling-client-context-in-wcf-web-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a

```
HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, HttpRequestMessage>
```

There you should be able to access the headers.

Comment: My issue isn't accessing the header values themselves, it is persisting the ClientContext object in a per-request manner. With standard WCF this is possible using the OperationContext. But with the Web API, OperationContext.Current is always null.